# How to get Eclipse to detect Java

Tags: macos, java, eclipse, osx-yosemite

I have always been able to use Eclipse without a problem. I had it installed on my Mac but when I switched to Yosemite I removed it. Now I have installed it again, but when I try to compile my Java code I get errors saying I need the JRE.

What I did already:

1. I used this version of Android + [Eclipse for Mac](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i).
2. I installed the JDK 8 from Oracle and JRE.
3. Made my project try to compile on 1.7 and 1.6 Java.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Error message:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Need to change Eclipse JRE for OS X 10.10 Yosemite](https://blog.winkelmeyer.com/2014/06/need-to-change-eclipse-jre-for-os-x-10-10-yosemite/) or [Java JRE Installation location Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite](http://code2care.org/pages/java-jre-installation-location-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-error/) or [Need to change Eclipse JRE for OS X 10.10 Yosemite](http://planetlotus.org/profiles/rene-winkelmeyer_125837) for procedures to get your JRE seen by Eclipse.

From what I understand you should be using this Java: [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). An older Apple JRE 1.6 for Lion/Mavericks purportedly won't work on Yosemite, but without trying that could be hearsay.