# How to run Minimus to minify files on mac?

Tags: macos, mac, java

I use minimus to minify my js scripts on my Mac. Why there is still the same error: `"To view this web content, you need to install the Java Runtime Environment"`, although I installed Java. What to do to fix this?

Comment: java isn't my forte, but is any of this any use to you? http://superuser.com/a/831445/347380

Answer (score 0):

This is because, it needs [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Just install, and everything will work.